# Execute System Command In LuaTeX

Tags: luatex, filesystem-access

(Edit: How to do file system operations and binary execution with LuaTeX in an OS-independent manner? I had written a set of macros for pdfTeX to do this using the `\write18` command. These macros were meant to be usable under both Windows and Linux, giving some "higher level" control. Now I wanted the macros to also support LuaTeX. My first experiments were unsuccessful, however. Trying to reduce the problem by omitting all macros and executing LuaTeX on the command line mislead the focus to an unimportant problem before I found a solution some days later.)

In a minimal testing environment (see
[Minimal Testing Environment For LuaMetaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/628065/minimal-testing-environment-for-luametatex))
I can do the initial memory dump

```
    luatex --ini ./plain.tex \dump
```

and then I would expect the following command to list the directory:

```
    luatex --fmt=./plain.fmt --shell-escape \directlua {os.execute ("dir")}\end
```

but it just tells me:

```
    This is LuaTeX, Version 1.13.2 (TeX Live 2021/W32TeX)
     system commands enabled.
    No pages of output.
    Transcript written on texput.log.
```

So how do I execute system commands under LuaTeX as it is possible under pdfTeX with `\write18`?

Comment: using luatex from texlive  `luatex --shell-escape '\directlua {os.execute ("dir")}\end'` lists all the files in the directory for me (I need the single quotes to protect the `\ ` from the commandline shell)

Comment: Thank you for testing, @David! Now, your very example gives me a fatal
error message: `! I can't find file \`''.` whereas it does indeed work for me
having exchanged double and single quotes:
`luatex --fmt=./plain.fmt --shell-escape "\directlua {os.execute ('dir')}\end"`.
That's fine, yet it looks as if LuaTeX's behavior were a bit unpredictable
across installations.

Comment: Similarly, quoting the primitive in `luatex --ini ./plain.tex "\dump"` works
whereas `luatex --ini ./plain.tex '\dump'` produces a 1 page, 180 bytes `plain.dvi` output.
`luatex --help` doesn't mention as syntax-conforming
any quoting of remaining commands to be processed by LuaTeX.

Comment: that quoting is not under the control of luatex, that is the syntax of whatever shell you use in the command line, windows shell and different unix shells have different rules for double and single quotes and backslashes

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to match the question to the answer, i.e., ask how you can write code for a cross-platform shell-escape aware check of a few things and then leave the answer as it is. Voting to close for now, it can be reopened after an edit.

Comment: Regarding the edit: now the question matches the answer a little bit better, bit it is still rather unclear and too much of a "story" about the command line attempt. I would recommend a complete rewrite of the question, removing the part about executing directlua commands from the command line, and instead adding the minimal document to the question but then without the parts that are necessary to solve the problem. Make it Q&A, a question with an answer to that question, not a series of forum posts about what you did.

Comment: Thank you, @Marijn, I will keep these thoughts in mind when posting any new question. I still have to learn how to contribute on this platform in a sensible way.

Answer (score 0):

I over-minimized this test by entering a LuaTeX command at the shell prompt without the necessary quoting, as @David explained, so I did not get the expected output. Within a document, the same command must not be quoted, and the problem shifts to getting the output from the system into a command sequence. The idea is being able to run under both `unix` and `windows` while failing gracefully under pdfTeX or if `--shell-escape` is not set.

```
    \def \system #1#2#3{{%
      % #1: unix command, #2: windows command, #3: control sequence (return value) 
      \xdef #3{}%
      \ifx \directlua \undefined
        \message {! No \string\directlua\space support (LuaTeX required).}%
      \else
        \edef \escapestate {\directlua {tex.write (status.shell_escape)}}%
        \def \one {1}%
        \ifx \escapestate \one
          \edef \ostype {\directlua {tex.print (os.type)}}%
          \def \unix {unix}% os.type can be "unix", "windows", or "msdos"
          \directlua {% 
            \ifx \ostype \unix
              local file = io.popen ([[#1]]);
              os.execute ([[#1]]);
            \else
              local file = io.popen ([[#2]]);
              os.execute ([[#2]]);
            \fi 
            local content = file:read "*a";
            file:close ();        
            tex.toks [5] = content; }%
          \xdef #3{\the \toks 5}%
        \else \message {! No --shell-escape switch set for system command.}\fi
      \fi }}  

    \bgroup \newlinechar = 10     
      \system {setterm --clear}{cls}\myresult  
      \system {time}{time /t}\myresult
        \message {^^JSystem time:^^J\myresult}   
      \system {cd}{cd}\myresult
        \message {^^JCurrent folder:^^J\myresult}  
      \system {ls -l}{dir /b}\myresult
        \message {^^JFiles in current folder:^^J\myresult}  
      \system {set}{set}\myresult
        \message {^^JEnvironment variables:^^J\myresult}  
    \egroup \end
```

Save above file as `curdir.tex` and run:

```
    luatex --fmt=plain --output-format=pdf --shell-escape ./curdir.tex \end
```

Comment: I don't see how this answers your question.

Comment: @José: Hope I could fix the issues.